# Javascript Dont Change The Background

Tags: javascript, html, background-color

I want to change my list background but it wont work

my code :

```
change(num, element){
var text

if (num == 1){ ... }
else if (num == 2) { ... }
else { ... }

document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = text;

document.getElementByClass("left").style.backgroundColor = "black"; //<------ 
element.style.backgroundColor = "white";                            //<------
}
```

and my html :

```
<ul>
   <li><a class="left" href="#" onclick="change(1,this)>First</a></li>
   <li><a class="left" href="#" onclick="change(2,this)>Second</a></li>
   <li><a class="left" href="#" onclick="change(3,this)>Third</a></li>      
</ul>
```

When i click on one of my list element , the text changes but background color won't ...

How i can fix this ?

Thanks,

Comment: Open your browser's developer tools. Look at the console. Read the error messages. Call a function that actually exists! Then look at the duplicate question for your second problem.

Comment: correct: document.getElementsByClassName(), (it returns array)
You are using document.getElementByClassName() (s missing)

Comment: @DineshPatra — getElementsByClassName doesn't return an array, just something that is like an array in some ways.

Comment: @Quentin, in the console (in this page) as there is a element with class name 'default', I tried this
typeof(document.getElementsByClassName('default')); it is returning object,
But I need to access innerHTML by document.getElementsByClassName('default')[0].innerHTML;

So i think its array'

Also as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

it says array like object

Comment: @DineshPatra — If you try `document.getElementsByClassName('default') instanceof Array` then you'll see that it is not an array. If you try `document.getElementsByClassName('default').forEach(...)` then it will error, but all arrays have a `forEach` method. It does not return an array.

Comment: @DineshPatra — It says "array like object" and not "array" because it is not an array.

Comment: @Quentin thank you for ur clarification. As per it's usage, I thought its array. But frankly I had only once used this. Otherwise I use document.querySelector();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such function as `getElementByClass`, there's only `getElementsByClassName`, wich returns an array. You need to choose the one you want to change out of this array or use ids